# Влияют ли тревоги на закрытие вопросов?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, тревоги

У меня ещё недостаточно репутации, чтобы голосовать за закрытие вопросов. Но я могу поставить тревогу на вопросе, если он дубликат или непонятна его суть. Но если моя тревога будет помечена как полезная, то повлияет ли она на закрытие вопроса?

Comment: При такой тревоге вопрос будет добавлен в очередь проверок на закрытие (если он еще не там), также его может закрыть модератор при ручной обработке тревоги (если вопрос не будет закрыт раньше через очередь проверок).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Влияют.

В описании привилегии о [тревогах на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) сказано следующее (цитирую только релевантную часть):

> ###### What happens to flags?
>
> Many flags are handled by other members of the site like yourself, who've earned review privileges. Flags to close a question (i.e. "needs improvement"), not an answer flags, and very low quality flags are primarily handled this way.

Многие тревоги обрабатываются другими участниками сайта, которые заработали соответствующую привилегию. Тревоги на закрытие вопроса (т.е. "требуется улучшение"), "не является ответом" и "очень низкое качество" в основном обрабатываются таким образом.

> Moderators may step in to handle flags that aren't handled by ordinary members of the site or the system.

Модераторы могут участвовать в обработке тревог, которые не были обработаны обычными участниками или системой.

> Finally, flags that aren't processed in a reasonable amount of time age away: close flags expire after between 4-14 days (depending on other votes and views).

Тревоги, которые не были обработаны за разумное время, исчезают: тревоги на закрытие протухают после 4-14 дней в зависимости от других голосов и просмотров.

---

При этом, отметка тревоги как полезной (если это сделал модератор) всего лишь значит, что модератор счёл её таковой. Но это не значит, что он закроет вопрос.